# How do I return keys from objects stored in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

How do I return the key from a collection of objects and calculate it with a recipe? I stuck in a for loop and already tried it with .reduce(). But I don't understand it good enough. Can someone help me or explain it to me? What is the best way to solve this?

```
var soup = { 
            potato: 3,
            onion: 1,
            corn: 5
            };

var gratin = {
            meat: 2,
            onion: 2,
            pea: 5
            };

var pizza = {
            cheese: 1,
            tomato: 3,
            oregano: 2
        };


var edoka = { // in a store, the values are the prices per ingredient
            cheese: 8,
            corn: 3,
            meat: 6,
            onion: 4,
            pea: 1,
            oregano: 7,
            potato: 5,
            tomato: 6
        };

        var were = {
            cheese: 6,
            corn: 2,
            meat: 9,
            onion: 5,
            pea: 2,
            oregano: 6,
            potato: 3,
            tomato: 3
        };

        var brutto = {
            cheese: 6,
            corn: 2,
            meat: 9,
            onion: 5,
            pea: 2,
            oregano: 8,
            potato: 3,
            tomato: 4
        };

        var allStores = { // this is an example of a "storeCollection"
            Brutto: brutto,
            Edoka: edoka,
            Were: were,
        };


function cheapestStoreForRecipe(recipe, storeCollection){
            // make it return the key for the store in storeCollection
            // that has the cheapest total cost for recipe. Feel free
            // to use costOfRecipe inside this function!  
        }
```

Comment: You need to better explain what you mean by “How do I return the key from a collection of objects and calculate it with a recipe”. However, to get keys from an Object, use: Object.keys(). With this you can iterate the objects and sum the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `reduce`:

```js
var soup = { potato:3, onion:1, corn:5 },
    gratin = { meat:2, onion:2, pea:5 },
    pizza = { cheese:1, tomato:3, oregano:2 };
    
var edoka = { cheese:8, corn:3, meat:6, onion:4, pea:1, oregano:7, potato:5, tomato:6 },
    were = { cheese:6, corn:2, meat:9, onion:5, pea:2, oregano:6, potato:3, tomato:3 },
    brutto = { cheese:6, corn:2, meat:9, onion:5, pea:2, oregano:8, potato:3, tomato:4 };

var allStores = {
  Brutto: brutto,
  Edoka: edoka,
  Were: were,
};


function cheapestStoreForRecipe(recipe, storeCollection) {
  var cheapest = Object.keys(storeCollection).reduce((result, name) => {
    var total = getStoreRecipePrice(storeCollection[name], recipe);
    if (result === null || total < result.total) {
      return {name, total};
    }
    return result;
  }, null);
  return cheapest;
}

function getStoreRecipePrice(store, recipe) {
  //                                                          price    *  quantity
  return Object.keys(recipe).reduce((total, key) => total + store[key] * recipe[key], 0);
}

console.log('soup: ', cheapestStoreForRecipe(soup, allStores));
console.log('gratin: ', cheapestStoreForRecipe(gratin, allStores));
console.log('pizza: ', cheapestStoreForRecipe(pizza, allStores));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not make complete sense, however, I think you’re looking for something like:

```
let soupTotal = 0;

Object.keys(soup).forEach(key => {
    soupTotal += soup[key];
});
```

There are of course other ways of achieving the same result, but this is simple and you should understand how this works.

If you’re only interested in the values, you can use `Object.values()`. To find the smallest value:

```
// get only the values
let arrayOfValues = Object.values(soup);
// find the smallest, using the “rest” operator
let smallest = Math.min(...arrayOfValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [blex's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60682897/4388775). If you want to go further design-wise, I would recommend to create properties name and ingredients for each of your recipe. Hence, you will not need to create an object indexed by name: `allStores`.

```js
const recipes = [
  { name: 'soup', ingredients: { potato: 3, onion: 1, corn: 5 } },
  { name: 'gratin', ingredients: { meat: 2, onion: 2, pea: 5 } },
  { name: 'pizza', ingredients: { cheese: 1, tomato: 3, oregano: 2 } },
  { name: 'edoka', ingredients: { cheese: 8, corn: 3, meat: 6, onion: 4, oregano: 7, pea: 1, potato: 5, tomato: 6 } },
  { name: 'brutto', ingredients: { cheese: 6, corn: 2, meat: 9, onion: 5, oregano: 8, pea: 2, potato: 3, tomato: 4, } },
];

function totalCost(recipe) {
  return Object.values(recipe.ingredients).reduce((total, v) => (total+v), 0)
}

function cheapestStoreForRecipe(recipes) {
  let cheapest = { name: recipes[0].name, total: totalCost(recipes[0]) }
  for (let i = 1; i < recipes.length; ++i) {
    const currentTotal = totalCost(recipes[i]);
    if (cheapest.total > currentTotal) {
      cheapest = { name: recipes[i].name, total: currentTotal };
    }
  }
  return cheapest;
}

console.log(cheapestStoreForRecipe(recipes));
```